# Confined Quantifiers - Re Expressing formula

Tags: first-order-logic

so I'm doing some study on Confined Quantification, and I understand how it when converting to english, but I don't understand how to re express the formula? I've tried watching videos but nothing has really helped me. The practice question is:

Re-express the following formulas using confined quantifiers, where the confining set is an integer interval.

(a) X =A1 ∨X =A2 ∨...∨X =An

(b) A1 ̸=A2 ∧A2 ̸=A3 ∧...∧An−1 ̸=An

Can anyone provide me an explanation on how to complete these? Much appreciated Thanks.

Comment: What are you meaning with "Confined Quantification" ? may you reference some sources, please ?

Comment: It's a practice question sheet from my Uni, it doesn't say anything else just: Re-express the following formulas using confined quantifiers, where the confining set is an integer interval. Under the question topic of Replacement tautologies

Comment: Maybe it is what is also called "bounded (or restricted) quantification", i.e. h $(\exists x)(A \land B)$ is abbreviated as $(\exists x)_A(B)$, or $(\exists x \in A)B$. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "Confined Quantification" is the same as [*restricted* (or guarded) quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification#Range_of_quantification), in order to :

> Re-express the following formulas using confined quantifiers, where the confining set is an integer interval :
>
> (a) $X = A_1 \lor X = A_2 \lor...\lor X = A_n$,

we must intorudece the set $N = \{1, 2, ... n \}$, we may re-express it as :

> > $(\exists i \in N)(X = A_i)$.

For

> (b) $A_1 \ne A_2 \land A_2 \ne A_3 \land... \land A_{n−1} \ne A_n$

we need $N' = \{1, 2, ... n-1 \}$:

> > $(\forall i \in N')(A_i \ne A_{i+1})$.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much for your assistance. That may be the reason I wasn't able to find anything on google.